# Is there way to hard code a two dimensional integer array without having to mention any dimension in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, hardcode

I can easily hard code 2D `char` arrays, avoiding specifying the last dimension, as below.

`char *mobile_games[] = { "DISTRAINT", "BombSquad" }`

Although, I can't do this...

`char *pc_games[] = { { 'F', 'E', 'Z' }, { 'L', 'I', 'M', 'B', 'O' } }`

The same warning pops up when I try something like...

`int *rotation[] = { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 } }`

I would like to know the exact reason as to why that happens, and how I can hardcode an `int` array by not having to mention the last dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to 2D arrays. You can't initialize a pointer like this, either:

```
int *int_array = {1, 2};
```

The reason it works for strings is because string literals decay to pointers when used in that context. That's why you can use a string literal in the argument list of a function that takes a `char *` parameter.

To do what you want, you need to declare it as a 2D array, rather than an array of pointers.

```
int rotation[][2] = { { 1, 0 }, {0, 1} };
```

If you really want an array of pointers, you will need to declare the row values separately.

```
int rot0[] = {1, 0};
int rot1[] = {0, 1};
int *rotation[] = {rot0, rot1};
```

Comment: or as I said, cast it

Comment: @Barmar Why is it that for an n-dimensional array the last n-1 sizes are necessary to be specified, but not the nth one?

Comment: @NikhilCSB It needs to know how big each stride is to convert indexes to pointer offsets. But the last size just tells it the full length of the array, which isn't needed.

Comment: I understand it better now. Thank you! @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

6.7.9 of the standard is quite clear:

> The initializer for a scalar...The initial value of the object is that of the expression (after conversion);...

and explains your warnings:

I was given an initialiser-list of two initialiser-lists:

```
main.c:4:26: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
  char *pc_games[] = { { 'F', 'E', 'Z' }, { 'L', 'I', 'M', 'B', 'O' } };
                         ^~~
```

the first of which contains integer character constants, which you told me to shove in a pointer, that's no good...

```
main.c:4:31: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
  char *pc_games[] = { { 'F', 'E', 'Z' }, { 'L', 'I', 'M', 'B', 'O' } };
                              ^~~
```

...but I tried with the first, and then I found another integer character constant which I have nothing I can do with, because the type you specified (`char *`) implies a scalar, did you mean an array of pointers? or better yet, an array of integers?

```
main.c:4:45: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
  char *pc_games[] = { { 'F', 'E', 'Z' }, { 'L', 'I', 'M', 'B', 'O' } };
                                            ^~~
```

...and then I went to the second initialiser-list you specified and tried to do the same conversion again...

```
main.c:4:50: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
  char *pc_games[] = { { 'F', 'E', 'Z' }, { 'L', 'I', 'M', 'B', 'O' } };
```

...and then I found more stray constants in the initialiser list. What's going on? Did you mean `char pc_games[2][5]`?

---

Q: I mistook `char *` for `char []`. Can I do `char s[] = {'f', 'e', 'z'};`?
A: Yes. 6.7.9p14 also allows

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

so `char s[] = {"fez"};` is also possible.